Understanding “as is” in Sentence Structure
In the sentence:

“The implementation should be exactly as is specified in the
document”

Is “as is” equivalent to “as (it) is”?
If not, what grammatical function does “as is” serve in this context? Is it acting as an adjective?
Additionally, what role does “specified in the document” play in the sentence? Is it functioning as an adverbial phrase modifying the entire sentence?
Thanks!

As looks adverbial to me, by introducing how "specified" and modifying the way the implementation should be (the verb). The sentence could be smoother.

as on the semantic level is more or less synonmous with "like".  "exactly as" = "exactly like".  like can mean "similar" but when it's modified by "just" or "exactly" it means "perfectly matching, perfecting following, perfectly obeying, etc".

Yes it is one of the contractions common in English. Any native speaker would understand what it means. Note that it can be shortened even further to just "as" without changing the meaning.
All the following mean the same.
“The implementation should be exactly as is specified in the document”
“The implementation should be exactly as it is specified in the document”
“The implementation should be exactly as specified in the document”
“The implementation should be exactly the same as [[it] is] specified in the document”

So clear! Thanks a lot! Even GPT cannot provide such a straightforward answer.

"Even ChatGPT?"  "Even" in that construction implies that ChatGPT is the gold standard.  ChatGPT doesn't know when it's dishing out incorrect and self-contradictory information, which it often does.
